# Database creation using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

Ok, so I have this code:

```
    <?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpwd = 'ALLO';
$dbname = 'test';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname);


if(! $conn )
{
  die("\nconn: $conn \nCould not connect: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}
echo "\n";







$createtab="CREATE TABLE People(FirstName CHAR(30),LastName CHAR(30),Age INT)";

// Execute query
if (mysqli_query($conn,$createtab))
  {
  echo "Table created successfully";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($conn);
  }

echo "\n";




mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO People (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES ('Peter', 'Griffin',35)");

mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO People (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES ('Glenn', 'Quagmire',33)");






mysqli_close($conn)
?>
```

When I run the php script, it runs fine.

However, I can't find the table in mysql workbench.

I refreshed many times.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX1sQ.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEXqT.png

Comment: phpmyadmin what does it say?

Comment: I ran the queries using `HeidiSQL`, the table and the rows showed up in mine...

Comment: Oh and it might be that mysql workbench doesn't have selected a default db.Insert in your code a CREATE DATABASE blah;USE blah; before the tables creation.OR just use a existing db.

Comment: USE? well, what do you mean? I did have a create database script before, but found it to be useless.

Comment: Yeah USE database_name so it knows what db to use

Answer (score 0):

See if this gives you any results:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='People'
```

if not,Create a db before any tables or ,judging from your screenshot just add a USE test in your code.

```
$createdb="USE test";

// Execute query
if (mysqli_query($conn,$createdb))
 {
  echo "Db selected";
 }
else
 {
  echo "Error selecting db: " . mysqli_error($conn);
 }
```

Comment: I get Db selected, but I can't see the table.

Comment: DROP test and recreate it.

Comment: Do you have all privileges on your user?

Comment: what do you mean by privileges? and how do i check?

Comment: i still get nothing. i changed phpmyadmin.conf to <Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096045/mysql-said-documentation-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-usi

Comment: still doesn't work. the tables appears in phpmyadmin, but not in mysql workbench

Comment: This means it works,I heard many people complain about mysql workbench,use http://www.heidisql.com/.