# Where is the ini file for wamp server for MYSQL Workbench integration?

Tags: wamp, mysql-workbench

I need the ini file, but I don't know which one I need to use.
[image]
[image]

Comment: `my.ini` is the MySQL config file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471856/database-creation-using-php-and-mysql, thanks, but i still can't integrate workbench with phpmyadmin though

Answer (score 1):

On WAMP Server the `my.ini` file can be found here, assuming you installed wamp on c:

```
c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z\my.ini
```

Remember to specify the section called [wampmysqld] when integrating with MySQL Workbench.