# I have Change configuration details in config.sample.inc.php. Still i getting error in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

My user name and password as 'root'. I have use Xampp server.
I am getting this error

> 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>
> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
>
> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server

Configuration details:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
```

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096045/mysql-said-documentation-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-usi

Comment: The configuration file is called config.inc.php; if you are changing config.sample.inc.php you'll need to copy/rename it.

Answer (score 0):

That error message isn't consistent with the configuration file you've posted -- it says the connection for the controluser failed, but you haven't pasted the controluser line. Generally (if you're not using the advanced features like bookmarks, user configuration, or change tracking) you won't need to define a controluser or controlpass. Try omitting those two lines from your configuration file and see if that helps.

Also, with the default auth_type of cookie, you don't need the user or password lines, either.