# Restart to default XAMPP or get access for user 'root'@'localhost after changing password

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

**Here is the technical information:**

XAMP : 7.2.10-0

MacOS High Sierra: 10.13.6

**Problem:**

I reseted the MySQL/MariaDB Root Password by using the mysqladmin command-line utility:

```
mysqladmin --user=root password "newpassword"
```

I know that my password change has been accepted, by attempting to connect to the MySQL/MariaDB server using the mysql command-line client in the same directory.

```
--user=root --password=newpassword -e "SELECT 1+1"
```

However, when I try to access myphp, I get

```
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I tried different solutions online, but none worked:

1. [MySQL said: Documentation #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096045/mysql-said-documentation-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-usi)

I am not able to change in config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']='NO'
```

because I don't have privileges. None of the solutions in the previous post helped

2. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75002/recovering-mysql-root-password-xampp/119749

Edited my.ini and insert skip-grant-tables below [mysqld]
Restart MySQL
I am able to get into phpmyadmin; however, I don't have user privileges.

**Is there a way to restart to default xampp? I would like to have it like it was before changing the password.**

Comment: Hello @EPaz, have you checked if there's other `MySQL` installed in your machine? That occasionally happens when you have other `MySQLs` or you don't run the `xampp` as admin (in Windows)

Comment: I don't have another MySQL on my machine, is the first time I am using MySQL and php

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience using MAC, basing on what you said `because I don't have privileges` you can try these: https://www.wikihow.com/Open-Applications-With-Root-Privileges-on-a-Mac

Comment: Ohh also, if you change the pass of your MySQL, try to exit and run (in admin privileges) xampp.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to how to restart XAMPP to default:

1. Delete the XAMPP-VM icon from the Applications folder.
2. Remove all XAMPP-VM data by deleting the ~/.bitnami folder within your home directory on the OS X host.

I was missing the delete of ~/.bitnami folder, reason why the past changes were saved.

Found at:
https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_stackman.html

Answer (score 0):

Login into MySQL using socket authentication.

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

or enter terminal by root privileges and run

```
mysql -u root
```

Then the following command could be run.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Comment: I cannot run sudo on the terminal inside xampp.

Comment: You can open use cmd. But you should open it run as administrator. Then you need type mysql -u root

Answer (score 0):

```
root@debian:~# mysql -u root -p
SET PASSWORD [FOR user] =
{
    PASSWORD('some password')
  | OLD_PASSWORD('some password')
  | 'encrypted password'
}enter code here
```

First, open the terminal through xampp, then after writing username and password, set a new password to '' , that is going to override the previous password and then you can access to mySQL and phpmyadmin.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/set-password/