# I can't open my phpMyAdmin page what I should to do? [on macbook]

Tags: mysql, macos, phpmyadmin

This is how it show when I tried to get in my phpMyAdmin

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL said: Documentation #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096045/mysql-said-documentation-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-usi)

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482371/fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-for-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 0):

please check mysql service running or not.Then try in terminal type mysql -u root (user name is root) -p hit enter ask password type password if connect then mysql working ok.
Then type this in your browser http://localhost/phpmyadmin