# Cannot access phpMyAdmin on localhost running XAMPP

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, xampp

I've installed XAMPP on my Windows machine and am trying to run WordPress locally. I had some issues connecing the wp database and now cannot access phpMyAdmin at all. Is there a way to fix this short of re-installing XAMPP?

I tried setting user names/passwords in XAMPP's `passwords.txt`, wordpress `wp-config.php`, php `config.inc.php` files. I uncomment and set the password in the `php.config.inc.php` file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']
```

When I try to go to phpmyadmin on localhost I get the error message:

Cannot connect: invalid settings.
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'ENTER_YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'ENTER_YOUR_PASS_HERE';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096045/mysql-said-documentation-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-usi) is similar. the 3rd answer.